# When was the Japanese film Rodan (1956) shown in the USA?

Tags: movie, kaiju

According to Wikipedia, *Radon*/*Rodan* was released in 1956 in Japan and 1957 in the USA.

> The King Brothers Productions 1957 theatrical release of Rodan was quite successful in its first run in the United States.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodan_(film)#U.S._release

I remember going to the Germantown Boys Club in Philadelphia in the summer(s) of about 1960 or 1961.  And I remember that one time they took us by bus to a theater to watch *Rodan*.  And I find it hard to believe that would have been as early as 1957.  So I wonder if there was some sort of re release of *Rodan* in the USA about 1960.  Or if second run theatres might show it around 1960.

Comment: [This poster](https://libraries.wm.edu/sites/default/files/images/MS00081_B4F8_Rodan1957Poster_001.jpg) is dated 1957. I'd expect that some movie theatres re-ran it a bunch of times in double or triple-headers with other monster movies, especially those that were less concerned about getting caught showing films outside their original release window.

Comment: The Keen Centre has movie programs from as late as 1963 showing Rodan as part of a monster mash of christmas-themed(?!?) films; https://www.keenecenter.org/godzilla_room1.html